# How do i load javascript on a specific custom post template via functions.php?

Tags: javascript

I want to load some javascript on a custom post template called progress-posts.php. Using:

```
if (is_page_template( 'progress-posts.php' )) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
```

...didn't seem to do anything. I thought maybe because this is a template for posts and not pages. The method I've found that works is:

```
if (is_single()) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
```

However I'd like the option of adding single posts to my site in the future which don't require this javascript to not load it.

Here's the full section in my functions file as it is now for clarity:

```
// Add Javascript files here
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
    if (is_page_template( 'page-templates/home.php' )) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'aosjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js', array(), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'aosjsinit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/aos-init.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
    if (is_page_template( 'page-templates/progress.php' )) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
    if (is_single()) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'humburgersjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/hamburgers.min.js', array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

How would I load it specifically for the custom post template I made and nothing else?

Comment: if (is_single()) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }

Comment: function build_js(){
    if( is_single() && get_post_type()=='CustomPostTypeName' ){
         wp_enqueue_script( 'progress-box', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/progress-boxes.min.js', array(), null, true );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_js');

Comment: @vikrantzilpe I thought this had worked but i was looking at the wrong page. It seemed to have no effect.

Comment: where did you are put js folder?

Comment: if (is_page_template( 'page-templates/home.php' )) { 
   //Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'aosjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js');
    wp_register_script( 'aosjsinit', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos-init.min.js');

 
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aosjs' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aosjsinit' );

}

Comment: @vikrantzilpe Can you *please* pay attention to the context of the question. The issue has nothing to do with the path to the JS file.

Comment: @hypnocyst When you say progress-posts.php is "a custom post template", what do you mean exactly? How was this template created, and how has it been assigned to a page?